# Referencing a specific function in python by namespace?

Tags: python

I included the os module into my program and now the standard file open() call is being occluded by os.open(), is there a way to reference a specific namespace ?

Comment: Do `import os` (which leaves `os` as its own namespace) instead of `from os import *` .  `import *` is bad for exactly this reason.

Comment: Less-good answer is to use `builtins.open`.

Comment: I like both because both answer my question.

Comment: Even worse answer is `del open`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution: don't do things like this:

```py
from os import *
```

Instead, do this:

```py
import os
```

Then, you can reference the `os` `open` function like this:

```py
os.open(something)
```

And the built-in open as `open(filename)`. If, however, something is shadowing a built-in function:

```py
import builtins
builtins.open(filename)
```